# Where does django store temporary upload files?

Tags: django, django-uploads

I have a Django/uwsgi/nginx stack running on CentOS. When uploading a large file to django (1GB+), I expect it to create a temp file in `/tmp` and I should be able to watch it grow as the upload progresses. However, I don't. `ls -lah /tmp` doesn't show any new files being created or changing in size. I even specified in my `settings.py` explicitly that `FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'` but still nothing.

I'd appreciate any help in tracking down where the temp files are stored. I need this to determine whether there are any large uploads in progress.

Comment: It depends on the Webserver. The request has the contents of the file. You can issue a request.read() to gets the content. Automagically Django has some parsers to make that file "usable" again.

Comment: As I mentioned, the web server is nginx. Django has special handling for uploaded files. See the link in stevedbrown's answer below. And my question is *where are the temp files*.

Answer (score 6):

They are stored in your system's temp directory. From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs:

> **Where uploaded data is stored**
>
> Before you save uploaded files, the data needs to be stored somewhere.
>
> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django
>   will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. This means that
>   saving the file involves only a read from memory and a write to disk
>   and thus is very fast.
>
> However, if an uploaded file is too large, Django will write the
>   uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your system's temporary
>   directory. On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to
>   generate a file called something like /tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload. If an
>   upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django
>   streams the data onto disk.
>
> These specifics -- 2.5 megabytes; /tmp; etc. -- are simply "reasonable
>   defaults". Read on for details on how you can customize or completely
>   replace upload behavior.

Additionally, this only happens after a given size, defaulted to 2.5MB

> FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE The maximum size, in bytes, for files that
>   will be uploaded into memory. Files larger than
>   FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE will be streamed to disk.
>
> Defaults to 2.5 megabytes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question because, as I said, the problem is that `ls -lah /tmp` doesn't show any temp files being created while the upload is in progress.

Comment: Also, you should be sure that the process (not just you, the logged-in user) has write access to the /tmp folder, or wherever you are directing it.

Answer (score 4):

I just tracked this down on my OS X system with Django 1.4.1.

In django/core/files/uploadedfile.py, a temporary file is created using django.core.files.temp, imported as tempfile

```
from django.core.files import temp as tempfile
```

This simply returns Python's standard tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile unless it's running on Windows.

To see the location of the tempdir, you can run this command at the shell:

```
python -c "import tempfile; print tempfile.gettempdir()"
```

On my system right now it outputs /var/folders/9v/npjlh_kn7s9fv5p4dwh1spdr0000gn/T, which is where I found my temporary uploaded file.